# How I know if the Vue app is mounted from javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-router

I have this code to run my Vue App:

```
if (document.getElementById('app') != null) {
  new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      data () {
          return {
              errors: [],
              django_context: CONTEXT
          }
      },
      created() {
          this.$store.dispatch('products/getProducts');
      },
      render: h => h(App),
  }).$mount("#app");
}
```

I need to know if the app was mounted with vanilla javascript. Ty

Comment: Can't you just set a global flag which you set to true after mounting the app? `window.mounted = true`.

Comment: It's mounted *if* you have an element with `id="app"` otherwise it is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that the `__vue__` property is set on your mount point.

```
const mountPointSelector = "#app";
// [...]
const mountPoint = document.querySelector(mountPointSelector);
if (mountPoint) {
    return mountPoint.__vue__;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Vue 3.x**

```
let VueAppInstance = null;
let containerSelector = "#app-container";
 
// check if app has been mounted already
const mountPoint = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
if (mountPoint && mountPoint.__vue_app__ !== undefined) {

    VueAppInstance = mountPoint.__vue_app__._instance.proxy;

} else {

   // create a new app instance
   VueAppInstance = createApp({
      .....
   }).mount(containerSelector);

}
```

Comment: with this solution i have thi error ReferenceError: _ is not defined, i am using plain javascript

Comment: "_." is using the Lodash library https://lodash.com/

Comment: ok i used it without it and work too

Comment: @cyril I removed the dependance on lodash.

Answer (score 0):

I had response on other thread really simple working for me

```
if( document.querySelector( DIV_inside_the_mount_point ) === null ){
 //do what you want if not mounted , content not present
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Vue has `mounted` lifecycle. So after `created` add

```
  mounted() {
      console.log("Mounted!");
  },
```

You can read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-component-lifecycle) for a detailed look at Vue's lifecycles

Comment: I need to know outside of the Vue app. for example from jquery.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.